# What kind of R object is this ? List of matrices, or matrix of matrices or something else

Tags: r

My colleague created this R object, but he does not work here any more.

I need to work with his R code, but I'm not able to figure out if the object he created is a List of matrices, or matrix of matrices or something else.

I did some queries on the object and a screen shot, hopefully this will give you an idea about the R object.

```
> dim(fmr.seg.crc)
[1] 10 22
> dimnames(fmr.seg.crc)
[[1]]
 [1] "s1"  "s2"  "s3"  "s4"  "s5"  "s6"  "s7"  "s8"  "s9"  "s10"

[[2]]
 [1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18"
[19] "19" "20" "21" "22"
> head(fmr.seg.crc[[1]])
     start  end    value
[1,]     1  576 2.030296
[2,]   577 1112 1.945320
[3,]  1113 1511 1.929819
[4,]  1512 2113 1.868648
[5,]  2114 2573 1.938822
[6,]  2574 3992 1.966110

> fmr.seg.crc[1,2]
[[1]]
       start    end    value
 [1,]      1   1683 2.009863
 [2,]   1684   3683 1.943753
 [3,]   3684   7272 2.004721
 [4,]   7273   7823 1.909030
 [5,]   7824  12166 2.021245
 [6,]  12167  13125 1.909732
 [7,]  13126  15006 2.040557
 [8,]  15007  16044 1.965647
 [9,]  16045  16598 2.039992
[10,]  16599  17470 2.107079
[11,]  17471  17521 2.021539
[12,]  17522  18364 1.942838
[13,]  18365  19195 2.094474
[14,]  19196  21016 2.021019
[15,]  21017  22644 1.970473
[16,]  22645  23065 2.030463
[17,]  23066  23689 2.134962
[18,]  23690  23823 2.037685
[19,]  23824  28197 2.012424
[20,]  28198  33313 2.042131
[21,]  33314  35797 1.991916
[22,]  35798  35824 2.025841
[23,]  35825  37962 2.062941
[24,]  37963  41552 2.021660
[25,]  41553  46006 2.046230
[26,]  46007  50217 2.014589
[27,]  50218  51558 1.945273
[28,]  51559  57890 2.019592
[29,]  57891  58896 2.117450
[30,]  58897  59443 2.052708
[31,]  59444  59533 2.029076
[32,]  59534  62300 1.971623
[33,]  62301  64252 2.047004
[34,]  64253  66429 1.980032
[35,]  66430  70187 2.039259
[36,]  70188  72583 1.999711
[37,]  72584  74952 2.037337
[38,]  74953  75459 1.994685
[39,]  75460  76248 1.907432
[40,]  76249  77551 1.974716
[41,]  77552  82026 2.026742
[42,]  82027  83915 1.971480
[43,]  83916  87782 2.021381
[44,]  87783  90469 2.059347
[45,]  90470  91817 2.000065
[46,]  91818  93625 2.080138
[47,]  93626  94351 2.033229
[48,]  94352  97927 2.002070
[49,]  97928 107217 2.059019
[50,] 107218 115066 2.033657
[51,] 115067 118643 2.082806
[52,] 118644 123727 2.043857
[53,] 123728 125791 2.095192
[54,] 125792 126639 2.056129
[55,] 126640 129253 2.025997
[56,] 129254 132674 2.071402
[57,] 132675 133815 1.993041
[58,] 133816 136346 2.053994
[59,] 136347 136743 1.997972
[60,] 136744 139120 1.963982
[61,] 139121 140701 2.059231
[62,] 140702 142317 1.983171
[63,] 142318 147205 2.032126
[64,] 147206 149266 1.958569
[65,] 149267 151682 2.007082
[66,] 151683 153611 1.956822
```

Screen shot of the object in R looks like this:

[image]

My task is to convert a regular input file with 4 columns into this R object.  My input data looks like this :

```
> head(seg2b)
     Chromosome     Start       End     value
[1,]          1     62920    462795 2.2251460
[2,]          1    462894  54574132 1.5044123
[3,]          1  54574878  54575365 0.2056125
[4,]          1  54576652 112147704 1.5074394
[5,]          1 112153343 112154768 2.4605827
[6,]          1 112163334 116601768 1.5106820
```

Comment: Instead of what you provided it would be much better to share `dput(fmr.seg.crc)`, or some part of `fmr.seg.crc`.

Comment: Have you looked at `typeof` or `class`?

Answer (score 2):

It is a matrix whose entries are lists consisting of one element, which is again a matrix. For instance,

```
m <- matrix(1:4, 2, 2)
(obj <- matrix(list(m, m, m, m), 2, 2))
#      [,1]      [,2]     
# [1,] Integer,4 Integer,4
# [2,] Integer,4 Integer,4

obj[1, 1]
# [[1]]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
```

Without further information it's not really clear what to do with your new input. Perhaps there is a separate submatrix for each new value of `Chromosome`. In your example you have only a single value of it, so then

```
(obj <- matrix(list(seg2b[, -1]), 1, 1))
#      [,1]  
# [1,] List,3

obj[1,1]
# [[1]]
#          Start       End     value
# [1,]     62920    462795 2.2251460
# [2,]    462894  54574132 1.5044123
# [3,]  54574878  54575365 0.2056125
# [4,]  54576652 112147704 1.5074394
# [5,] 112153343 112154768 2.4605827
# [6,] 112163334 116601768 1.5106820
```

But I guess in your full input data there are multiple `Chromosome` values. As to give a full answer, it is necessary to know what columns and rows of `obj` represent.

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback !!  Wow, never heard of "lists consisting of one element, which is again a matrix" before. So complicated. So this R object is segment information from copy number data for 10 samples and 22 chrom. So the fmr.seg.crc is a matrix of 10 rows and 22 cols. Each element of the matrix is the segment info for each sample & chromosome. I tried doing a ```dput``` its a very large file - not sure I can upload here. Also looked at typeof and class. ```typeof``` shows "list" and ```class``` shows "matrix". Thank you for the input! Let me try this out and see what I get

Comment: @kay, no problem. So it sounds like you can do `obj <- matrix(split(data.frame(seg2b)[-1], seg2b[, 1], drop = FALSE), ncol = 22, byrow = TRUE)` in case the first column of `seg2b` consists of blocks for chromosomes 1, 2, ..., 22, 1, 2, ..., 22, 1, 2, etc. and if each 22 correspond to different samples. The only different is that it instead of "..., which is again a matrix" we would have "..., which is a data frame". In case you wish to have matrices everywhere, add `obj[] <- lapply(obj, as.matrix)` afterwards.